# Check if string in input box is equal to varbinary(max) in SQL SERVER, PHP | SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlsrv

I'm having a problem with my login page.

I'm converting my password from string to `varbinary(max)`, my problem now is how can I compare or verify if my string inputted for logging in is equal to the stored data in the table.

Example.

The value of my password before being converted is **12345**. After being converted via `CONVERT(varbinary(max),'12345')`, the data now reflects as `0x3132333435`.

How will I be able to verify if my inputted password (12345) in my input box is similar to the value if converted into varbinary(max) 0x3132333435?

I'm using SQL SERVER 2012, XAMPP, and SQLSRV for conncetion.

Thank you so much in advance.

This is my *login.php*

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'includes/conn.php';

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $sql = "
SELECT username,cast(password as varchar(max)) as password 
FROM usermasterfile 
WHERE username ='$username'";

        include 'query/sqlsrv_query-global.php';

        if (sqlsrv_num_rows($query) < 1) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Cannot find account with the username';
        } else {
            $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($password == $row['password']) {
                $_SESSION['employeeidno'] = $row['employeeidno'];
            }
            else{
                $_SESSION['error'] = 'Incorrect password';
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Input credentials first';
    }

    header('location: index.php');
?>
```

**EDIT: FIXED IT!**

`````
SELECT *,cast(password as varchar(max)) as maxpassword 
FROM usermasterfile 
WHERE username ='$username'";````
`````

Comment: @Dharman Thanks for the heads up. I just finished fixing the login, i'm going to re-code everything now to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast your varbinary back to varchar value as

```
SELECT cast(0x3132333435 as varchar(max)) as varchar_value

varchar_value
-------------
12345
```

So, use the above casting in your code's comparison part.

Comment: How will I be able to implement that in php? ````$password = $_POST['password'];````?

Comment: @pjustindaryll Sorry, I don't know how can you manage in php.